# next is not a function. Nodejs http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate

Tags: node.js, api, jwt, passport.js, restful-authentication

I am developing a mean app login/registration using jwt and passport. Using local storage i am saving token but it is not getting saved in local storage.
It also says that `next is not a function` in my `controller.js`. On the other hand registration is working perfectly fine.

contoller.js

```
   module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    // call for passport authentication
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {       
        // error from passport middleware
        if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
        // registered user
        else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ "token": 
     user.generateJwt() });
        // unknown user or wrong password
        else return res.status(404).json(info);
    })(req, res);
   }
```

index.router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ctrlUser = require('../controllers/user.controller');

const jwtHelper = require('../config/jwtHelper');

router.post('/register', ctrlUser.register);
router.post('/authenticate', ctrlUser.authenticate);
router.get('/profile',jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, ctrlUser.userProfile);

module.exports = router;
```

login.component.ts

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm){
    this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userService.setToken(res['token']);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
      },
      err => {
        this.serverErrorMessages = err.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

user.service

```
  login(authCredentials){
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+'/authenticate', authCredentials, this.noAuthHeader);
  }


  setToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  deleteToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  getUserPayload() {
    var token = this.getToken();
    if (token) {
      var userPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
      return JSON.parse(userPayload);
    }
    else
      return null;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
    if (userPayload)
      return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    else
      return false;
  }

  getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/profile');
  }
```

```
TypeError: next is not a function
    at attempt (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:186:32)
    at authenticate (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
    at module.exports.authenticate (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\controllers\user.controller.js:37:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\fulinkedFolder\flogin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `next` function along with `req` and `res`:

```
module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {

    // ...

  })(req, res, next) // Pass 'next' here
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is resolved but now it is giving `Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"`. Here
`passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) =>`

Comment: Have you registered the local strategy with `passport.use(new LocalStrategy( ... ))`?

Comment: Thanks man I forgot to include that `passportConfig` file in `app.js` !